# python mock and libraries that are not installed

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest

I am working on software for a robot, which is normally run on the Raspberry Pi. Let's consider the imports of two files:

`motor.py` (runs the motors):

```
from RPi import GPIO as gpio
```

and `client.py` (communicates with the server and relays commands to the motors):

```
from rpi.motor import Motor
```

Both files are in a directory called `rpi`, which contains a `__init__.py` and a `__main__.py`. The `RPi` package cannot be installed on non-RPi devices. However, I still want to test the functionality of `client.py`.

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
# Location A


class TestClient(unittest.TestCase):
    # Location B
    setUp(self):
         # Location C
         pass
```

Originally, I tried `from rpi.client import Client` at LocA, but that failed because it tried to import Motor, and then import GPIO from RPi, which doesn't exist. I also tried `mock.patch("rpi.client.Motor")` at LocB (including adding `mock_motor` after `self`, and imported `Client` at LocC, but that failed as well. I tried mocking `RPi` at LocA, too, but it didn't work either.

How do you mock out a library that is not installed on your system?

Answer (score 13):

You can use [`patch.dict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-dict) to patch `sys.modules` and mock `RPi` module as showed in pointed documentation.

Use follow code at the top of your test module:

```
>>> from mock import MagicMock, patch
>>> mymodule = MagicMock()
>>> patch.dict("sys.modules", RPi=mymodule).start()
>>> from RPi import GPIO as gpio
>>> gpio
<MagicMock name='mock.GPIO' id='139664555819920'>
>>> import os
>>> os
<module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>
```

In Python3 you have same behavior.

---

In your specific case use `patch.dict` is little bit overkill; maybe you aren't interested in patch context and original state recover. So you can simplify it by set `sys.modules["RPi"]` directly:

```
>>> from unittest.mock import MagicMock
>>> mymodule = MagicMock()
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules["RPi"] = mymodule
>>> from RPi import GPIO as gpio
>>> gpio
<MagicMock name='mock.GPIO' id='140511459454648'>
>>> import os
>>> os
<module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python3.4/os.py'>
```

Comment: I've verified that is a correct solution. To make the answer better I would expand on sys.modules.

Comment: As you can read at https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-dict `patch.dict()` default behavior preserve original dictionary and just inject new values. Anyway I integrated my answer with some other notes to make it more clear.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico But what happens if you are importing `RPi` in a separate module other than your test module? how do you patch it then?