# Mocking a module imported inside of a function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

Is it possible to mock a module that's imported inside of a function?

for instance

```
def my_func(input):
    import something_else
    something_else.do_something(input)
```

I have an import inside of the function because of a circular dependency.  Based on my googling I think I am SOL, but was wondering if anyone knew of way to make this possible.

I just want to verify that do_something gets called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the same technique that's described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32539237/4101725). In short you can patch `sys.modules` dict. So your test can be:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

...

def test_call_do_something(self):
    m = MagicMock()
    with patch.dict("sys.modules", something_else=m):
        input_mock = MagicMock()
        my_func(input_mock)
        m.do_something.assert_called_with(input_mock)
```

You can rewrite it by `patch` decorator, but `m` should be a static instance.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Didn't know you could do that.  How would this example change if instead of importing something_else, the import statement is `from some import thing_else`?

Comment: You mean that you have `from m import a` in a function? I can cover it later in the WE.

Comment: If I understand correctly It should work either in these cases.